# Pyspark orderBy asc nulls last

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In spark sql, you can use `asc_nulls_last` in an orderBy, eg

```
df.select('*').orderBy(column.asc_nulls_last).show
```

see [Changing Nulls Ordering in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381678/changing-nulls-ordering-in-spark-sql).

How would you do this in pyspark?

I'm specifically using this to do a "window over" sort of thing:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'rank',
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('group_id').orderBy('datetime'))
)
```

where the `datetime` column can be a datetime or null.

I was hoping to do it with:

```
...orderBy(expr('column asc NULLS last'))
```

But this errors with `Exception: mismatched input 'NULLS' expecting <EOF>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn(
    'rank',
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('group_id').orderBy(F.col('datetime').asc_nulls_last()))
)
```